# How can i iterate through nested arrays of objects and remove some attribute

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JavaScript objects where each object can have children and the type of children is same as the type of parent again the children can have multiple children. I want to iterate through all the nodes and change some value.

```
[
    {
        "text": "Auto",
        "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
        "state": {
            "opened": true,
            "selected": true
        }
    },
    {
        "text": "BookMark1",
        "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
        "state": {
            "opened": true
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "BookMark2",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                }
            },
            {
                "text": "BookMark3",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                }
            },
            {
                "text": "BookMark4",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                }
            },
            {
                "text": "BookMark5",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                }
            },
            {
                "text": "BookMark6",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "BookMark2",
                        "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "BookMark3",
                        "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                        "state": {
                            "opened": true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "BookMark7",
                "icon": "/libs/jstree/folder.png",
                "state": {
                    "opened": true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the above object I want to iterate through all the nodes and remove the "state" attribute. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Create a recursive function, you're welcome!

Comment: checkout my answer it solves it

Comment: `state` is not an "attribute", it's a "property".

Comment: as your obj is a valid json use the `JSON.parse()` function with the reviver parameter it will visit all the nodes and you can modify certain property

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function removeKeys(arr, key) {
    arr.forEach(function (element, index) {
        delete element[key];
        if (element.children !== undefined) removeKeys(element.children, key);
    });
}

removeKeys(json, "state");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9scd3qb3/

Comment: Dom elements have property children not Object and Arrays

Comment: What does the `index` argument do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is recursive way to do it, it checks inside and outside.

**https://jsfiddle.net/8ku7wohd/2/**

```
function removeState(a){
    if (a.hasOwnProperty('state')) delete a['state'];
    if (a instanceof Array) a.forEach(removeState);
    else if (a instanceof Object) for (var k in a) removeState(a[k]);                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate with a recursive function over your objects. I created here for you a sample and most common way to walk trough nested objects:

```
function walk(item){
    for(index in item){
        console.log(item[index]);
        if(typeof item[index] == "object"){ 
            walk(item[index]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Using this function as base you may extend its functionality and do whatever you exactly need. If you are using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) they provide the function `.each(function(index, item){})` which does the same.

If I may help in something else update your post or comment here.

Comment: jQuery's `.each` recurses?

Comment: No it doesnt recurse, I meant that is a sustitute for `for`

Comment: Before pointing out jQuery's `.each`, since there was no hint of jQuery being wanted or allowed, I'd point out `Array#forEach`. By the way, your logic will fail if `item[index]` is null, since `typeof null` is `"object"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` with a `replacer` parameter to do it this way:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object, ['text', 'icon', 'children']))
```

The [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Example_with_an_array) gives a list of "whitelisted" properties to include in the results. All other properties (including `state`) are ignored/removed.

Answer (score -1):

Give this a try:

```
jQuery.each(myJSONObject, function(i, val) {
    delete val.state;
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0taL26cx/2/)

Update:

Another solution which needs a temporary var.

```
var tempJsonObject = [];
jQuery.each(myJSONObject, function(i, val) {
    delete val.state;
    tempJsonObject[i] = val;
});

myJSONObject = tempJsonObject;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0taL26cx/1/)

Update:

Included removing `state` property on child objects.

```
removeProperty(myJSONObject, "state");

function removeProperty(myJSONObject, prop) {
    jQuery.each(myJSONObject, function(i, val) {
        delete val.state;

        if(val.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
          removeProperty(val.children, "state");
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0taL26cx/4/)

Comment: It's not removing the state from children objects.

Comment: @DipeshGupta Not sure why, it does on the fiddle. Also added other solution, have a look.

Comment: Checked it, But it's not working. In console check for the childrens of second object. All the childrens are having "state"

Comment: @DipeshGupta Ah ok, didn't saw that. Post Updated.

Answer (score -3):

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(text);
for (var i in jsonObj) {
   console.log(jsonObj[i].text);
   jsonObj[i].text = "some text"
   var innerJson = jsonObj[i].children
   for (var j in innerJson) {
       console.log(innerJson[j].text);
       innerJson[j].text = "some other text for all inner"
   }
};
```

Comment: This might work if the level of nesting is only two, but in my case level of nesting is not fixed. Again the children can have childrens

Comment: You can always write a recursive method. Let me know if you want me to write code for you.